# Yii active record data saving in php7, Yii 1.1.17 ,OCI8 2.1 getting errors

Tags: php, yii, oci8

I developed the site under the PHP 5.5 with Oracle Db ,when I install the PHP 7 inserting or updating active record query is not working.. but when I used the create command query is working prefect.

for e.g My Datatype field is VARCHAR2 and I try to inserting the value "123" using active record but not working, when I changed the value "test" and try to insert using active record it's insert. I thought PHP 7 is stick comparison datatype value.

Can you please provide any solution how to work active record and Cdbcriteria query on PHP7?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Yii1 and php 7!!!   use PHP 5.6 ))) or yii2

Comment: Site is live , We can't rewrite codes again in Yii 2

Comment: Ruefully. But what erors in error log?

Comment: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SAK_ANNOUNCMENTS" "t" WHERE ACTIVE_TO >= :date1 and TEAM_ID LIKE '%24%'. Bound with :date1='29-02-2016'



             @@@@I am getting such type of errors , when I am doing select query.